# URL and mapRoute for local web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am new to web service and I have a pre-existing web service in mvc.

I am trying to host it locally.  But whenever I tried to access it ex: `http://localhost:11021/MyService` it would throw the HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.

I figured I need the full path to access it but am having trouble finding it.

I noticed that the map route is registered as follow

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Ping", // Route name
"Service/Ping/{typeId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Ping" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Naively I tried something like `http://localhost:11021/MyService/Ping` and it did not work.
What should the full url path be if I want to access the service and the ping service method?

Thanks

Comment: Is typeId an optional parameter?

Comment: yup it is, I tried ``http://localhost:11021/MyService/Ping/1`` as well but it returns ``HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found``

Comment: It should be http://localhost:11021/Service/Ping/1 according to your route.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `typeId` parameter optional. Also you may need to change "Service" to "MyService"

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Ping", // Route name
"MyService/Ping/{typeId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Ping", typeId  = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVC 4:

- you must install

  -.net framework 4.5
  -Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4
- Use application pool : ASP.Net 4 Integrated Pipeline
- Change your web.config file add 
  modules `<runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` under `<system.webServer>`